# how connect this table to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this user table files php from `easyui` http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/app/crud.php ,  but i not know how connect to MySQL

**users.php**

```
<style type="text/css">
        #fm{
            margin:0;
            padding:10px 30px;
        }
        .ftitle{
            font-size:14px;
            font-weight:bold;
            color:#666;
            padding:5px 0;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
        }
        .fitem{
            margin-bottom:5px;
        }
        .fitem label{
            display:inline-block;
            width:80px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var url;
        function newUser(){
            $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','New User');
            $('#fm').form('clear');
            url = 'save_user.php';
        }
        function editUser(){
            var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
            if (row){
                $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','Edit User');
                $('#fm').form('load',row);
                url = 'update_user.php?id='+row.id;
            }
        }
        function saveUser(){
            $('#fm').form('submit',{
                url: url,
                onSubmit: function(){
                    return $(this).form('validate');
                },
                success: function(result){
                    var result = eval('('+result+')');
                    if (result.success){
                        $('#dlg').dialog('close');      // close the dialog
                        $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                    } else {
                        $.messager.show({
                            title: 'Error',
                            msg: result.msg
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        function removeUser(){
            var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
            if (row){
                $.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to remove this user?',function(r){
                    if (r){
                        $.post('remove_user.php',{id:row.id},function(result){
                            if (result.success){
                                $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                            } else {
                                $.messager.show({   // show error message
                                    title: 'Error',
                                    msg: result.msg
                                });
                            }
                        },'json');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    </script>

    <h2>Basic CRUD Application</h2>
    <div class="demo-info" style="margin-bottom:10px">
        <div class="demo-tip icon-tip">&nbsp;</div>
        <div>Click the buttons on datagrid toolbar to do crud actions.</div>
    </div>

    <table id="dg" title="My Users" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:700px;height:250px"
            url="get_users.php"
            toolbar="#toolbar" pagination="true"
            rownumbers="true" fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th field="firstname" width="50">First Name</th>
                <th field="lastname" width="50">Last Name</th>
                <th field="phone" width="50">Phone</th>
                <th field="email" width="50">Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <div id="toolbar">
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-add" plain="true" onclick="newUser()">New User</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-edit" plain="true" onclick="editUser()">Edit User</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-remove" plain="true" onclick="removeUser()">Remove User</a>
    </div>

    <div id="dlg" class="easyui-dialog" style="width:400px;height:280px;padding:10px 20px"
            closed="true" buttons="#dlg-buttons">
        <div class="ftitle">User Information</div>
        <form id="fm" method="post" novalidate>
            <div class="fitem">
                <label>First Name:</label>
                <input name="firstname" class="easyui-validatebox" required="true">
            </div>
            <div class="fitem">
                <label>Last Name:</label>
                <input name="lastname" class="easyui-validatebox" required="true">
            </div>
            <div class="fitem">
                <label>Phone:</label>
                <input name="phone">
            </div>
            <div class="fitem">
                <label>Email:</label>
                <input name="email" class="easyui-validatebox" validType="email">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="dlg-buttons">
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-ok" onclick="saveUser()">Save</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-cancel" onclick="javascript:$('#dlg').dialog('close')">Cancel</a>
    </div>
```

**conn.php**

```
<?php

$conn = @mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','root');
if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb', $conn);

?>
```

**get_users.php**

```
<?php
    $page = isset($_POST['page']) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1;
    $rows = isset($_POST['rows']) ? intval($_POST['rows']) : 10;
    $offset = ($page-1)*$rows;
    $result = array();

    include 'conn.php';

    $rs = mysql_query("select count(*) from users");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
    $result["total"] = $row[0];
    $rs = mysql_query("select * from users limit $offset,$rows");

    $items = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
        array_push($items, $row);
    }
    $result["rows"] = $items;

    echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

and this MySQL database

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `firstname` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `phone` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: mysql is deprecated, use PDO instead. Using @ is not a best practises at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad that it didn't connect. Stop using `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated. Switch to [**PDO**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Rewrite your connection like this.

```
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

[`How to write queries using PDO ?`](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Prepared-Statement-P550.html)

Comment: where need add my database details? (mane database, password, host etc)

Comment: // configuration
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "my_db_name";
$dbuser     = "my_db_user";
$dbpass     = "my_db_pass";


{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

Comment: You get a blank page `http://swapes.com/proba/conn.php` which means connection is successful. You need to rewrite your queries to PDO as shown in the example.

Comment: but is not working ,a blank page see and when i not add the date mysql

Comment: is connected but not extract data from mysql